# why the constructor is getting called here?

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion, typecasting-operator

I have question on the below code. In the main function what will happen when the line: obj = 20; is executed. I am not able to understand why it calls the constructor? Could anyone of you please explain?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Int {
    int x;
  
public:
    Int(int x_in = 0)
        : x{ x_in }
    {
        cout << "Conversion Ctor called" << endl;
    }
    operator string()
    {
        cout << "Conversion Operator" << endl;
        return to_string(x);
    }
};
int main()
{
    Int obj(3);
    string str = obj;
    obj = 20;
    string str2 = static_cast<string>(obj);
    obj = static_cast<Int>(30);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler makes a list of possible candidates for `Int.operator=(int)`, one of them being `Int.operator=(Int const& value = Int(20))`.  Those candidates are based on a ranking, and that particular one wins.  You can remove the constructor from consideration by `explicit` tagging it:  `explicit Int(int x_in = 0)`

Comment: @Eljay It is actually `Int.operator=(Int&& value = Int(20))` that wins.

Answer (score 2):

Within the class there is not defined the assignment operator `operator =( int )`. But the class has the conversion constructor

```
Int(int x_in = 0)
```

So in this statement

```
obj = 20;
```

there is called the constructor like `Int( 20 )` to convert the integer value to an object of the type `Int` that can be assigned to the object `obj` due to the implicit move assignment operator generated by the compiler.

Comment: @user17732522 You are right.:)

Answer (score 1):

Lacking a assignment operator taking `int`, your compiler uses the next best assignment operator it can get it's hands on, which is the implicitly declared move assignment operator (`Int::operator=(Int&&)`). To use this operator, a rvalue reference to a `Int` object is required, which the compiler creates using the constructor `Int::Int(int)`, i.e. the compiler treats `obj = 20;` as

```
obj.operator=(Int(20));
```

To see what's happening here, you could implement the move assignment operator yourself to print something to the console when the assignment operator is executed:

```
class Int
{
...
public:
...


    Int& operator=(Int&& other)
    {
        std::cout << "move assignment of Int, new value: " << other.x << '\n';
        x = other.x;
        return *this;
    }

    // the following members are only declared to make sure the available
    // constructors/operators are the same as in the original version of the code
    Int(Int&&) = default;
    Int& operator=(Int const&) = default;
    Int(Int const&) = default;
};
```